# Error in Customizing Platooning on Plexe 3.0 version

Tags: simulator, sumo, plexe

I had installed plexe 3.0 and made changes to certain files to incorporate a new model. It is given in the documentation of Plexe on how to do it. Refer the below link to see what changes i did: https://plexe.car2x.org/tutorial/example2/

I am encountering the below error while running the simulator:

RUNTIME ERROR. A cRuntimeError exception is about to be thrown, and you
requested (by setting debug-on-errors=true in the ini file) that errors
abort execution and break into the debugger.
<!> Invalid controller selected -- in module (plexe::SinusoidalScenario) Highway.node[0].scenario (id=10), at t=1.01s, event #103
TRAPPING on the exception above, due to a debug-on-errors=true configuration option. Is your debugger ready?
zsh: trace trap  plexe_run -u Cmdenv -c SinusoidalNoGui -r 6
Step #0.00 (0ms ?*RT. ?UPS, TraCI: 53ms, vehicles TOT 0 ACT 0 BUF 0)            Step #1.00 (1ms ~= 10.00*RT, ~8000.00UPS, TraCI: 3ms, vehicles TOT 8 ACT 8 BUF 0plexe:~/src/plexe/examples/platooning% Error: tcpip::Socket::recvAndCheck @ recv: peer shutdown
Quitting (on error).
[Warning: Program was compiled without debug info, you might not be able to debug.]
<!> Error launching TraCI server ("sumo --remote-port 45779 --seed 0 --configuration-file ./sumocfg/freeway.sumo.cfg"): exited with code 1. Make sure you have set $PATH correctly. -- in module (veins::TraCIScenarioManagerForker) Highway.manager (id=5), during network initialization.
What can i do to solve it?

I tried changing certain sumo and plexe files to incorporate another model mycc which is a platooning model which should run showing the gui of the vehicles mob=ving accordingly.